# Remember me en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quiero de su orientacion, alguien me puede explicar cual es la utilidad de **Remember me** en Laravel?

EL codigo que tengo funciona, guarda el **token** en BD y todo, pero he probado y no he visto alguna utilidad.

Podria por favor explicarme cual es la utilidad? para que sirve? como puedo probar su utilidad?

Gracias de verdad, se que parece una pregunta de un aprendiz pero la verdad es lo que les digo, no he visto alguna utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Para que sirve la feature de `remember_me`?

> Cuando estas trabajando con sesiones en Laravel, puedes tener la
>   necesidad de habilitar que la sesión del usuario se mantenga activa,
>   es decir que aunque se mueva de pestaña del navegador o que cierre el
>   navegador por ejemplo su inicio de sesión se mantenga.

Para lograr eso tu tabla users debe tener una columna

`remember_token`

Que de hecho en las migraciones la puedes observar con esta estructura, esta columna la encontrarás en la migración `users`:

```
$table->rememberToken();
```

Si haces eso en tu sistema de logueo, es decir en tu HTML debe existir

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember">
```

Después de eso verás en tu navegador en la siguiente ruta:

1.- abrir el modo de `debug` o las herramientas de `desarrollador`
2.- ir a la pestaña `resources`
3.- ir del lado izquierdo a `cookies`

En esta última ubicación encontrarás que por cada vez que inicia un usuario una sesión, se generan dos datos relevantes:

```
XSRF-TOKEN //esta es una cookie que genera laravel para validar las peticiones que 
hace el usuario

laravel_session //ayuda a identificar la instancia de sesión creada por cada 
usuario activo dentro del sistema
```

ambos son una cadena de texto y números que validan cada petición del usuario que esta interactuando en el sistema, de modo que las peticiones que el user haga a través de los verbos HTTP sean aceptadas

**Ahora para activar que el framework ayude a recordar el inicio de sesión y el usuario no quede privado de interactuar dentro de**

Se hace lo siguiente

Si al momento de iniciar sesión seleccionas el checkbox anterior, laravel creará un:

```
remember_NHYi87Buyt67Tbhh
```

> Que no es otra cosa que una cadena que ayuda a identificar como válido
>   el inicio de la sesión para no cerrarla y requerir las credenciales de
>   nuevo; de modo que aunque el usuario cierre el navegador si lo vuelve
>   a abrir la sesión seguirá activa hasta que el tiempo de vida de la
>   cookie se termine

Por ejemplo si te vas a la ruta: *appname/config/session.php* te vas a dar cuenta que el tiempo máximo de vida que tiene asignado por defecto es de 120 minutos

Comment: Hola Alfredo...muchisimas gracias por explicar esto...sin embargo ya entiendo porque no veia la utilidad, sucede que aunque nunca marque la opcion de remember me... si cambio de pestaña o si cierro el navegador (Siempre y cuando en el app/config/Session.php tenga habilitado la variable exit_on_close false) siempre el usuario se mantiene conectado, es decir, no me pide de nuevo credenciales o algo por el estilo....sabrás el porque?

Comment: no al momento no tengo respuesta a eso que mencionas disculpa @joseangarita

Comment: Es extraño...porque yo he verificado que si se cree la cookie de remember y que se guarde en la base de datos...pero lo marque o no lo marque...no me funciona como se supone que deberia...de echo por seguridad tengo la opcion en el controlador que dice viaRemember y con todo y eso si el usuario cierra el navegador y lo abre de nuevo puede navegar no le pide de nuevo credenciales....si no configuro exit_on_close y lo dejo estándar al cerrar y abrir el navegador la sesión se mantiene. El laravel que uso es la versión 5.2

Answer (score 1):

En su momento no supe para que servía Remember me...les explicare para el que no lo sepa.

Remember me en Laravel, lo que hace es mantener la sesión activa, las sesiones tienen en Laravel por defecto 120 minutos de vida, si la cookie de sesión muere se cierra la sesión.

Si haces clic en Remember me, la sesión nunca muere y se mantiene activa, hasta que decidas cerrar la sesión por tu cuenta.

Saludos.